# I can not import the javascript file in my android studio

Tags: javascript, android-studio, import, calculator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzP8n.png)

I'm creating the calculator in android studio in which i was trying to import the two file such as "import org.mozilla.JavaScript.Context;" and "import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;". this two libraries file i want to use it but i can not ...in error they show "try to resolve class reference" .... so anyone can help me out to reslove the problem.

Comment: How are you including the `org.mozilla.javascript` library in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Add the Rhino Library to your Project in build.gradle by adding `implementation 'org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.13'`.
then check if you are importing it properly.
`import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;`
`import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;`